# Looping through array in bash

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to launch multiple python scripts with bash, for the purpose of later processing the data these scripts generate.

```
MYPIES=("/path/to/a.py" "path/to/b.py" "path/to/c.py" ... "path/to/xyz.py" )

for i in "${MYPIES[@]}"
  do
    python ${MYPIES[i]} &
  done
```

However this snippet causes the following error:

> syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/path/to/a.py")

Comment: BTW, all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use by [POSIX-specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) convention. As such, `MYPIES` should ideally be `mypies`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable `i` holds the filenames, it is not index to an entry in MYPIES.

```
MYPIES=("/path/to/a.py" "path/to/b.py" "path/to/c.py" ... "path/to/xyz.py" )

for i in "${MYPIES[@]}"
  do
    python "$i" &
  done
```

Comment: Should quote the expansion: `python "$i" &` -- otherwise a name with characters in IFS or which evaluates as a glob is liable to behave surprisingly.